# HttpsURLConnection In Android

Tags: android

I am learning the networking in android so that I can get the contents from the website API. I was going through the Udacity tutorial and got to know these lines of code required to make the HttpURLConnection. But what if I have to pull the contents from Https URL. Please suggest what modification is required in the below code for HttpsURL connection.

***HttpURLConnection :***

```
private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
            String jsonResponse = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.connect();
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the exception
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return jsonResponse;
```

Comment: this link might help you http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
readFromStream(inputStream);
```

This line of code is responsible for reading the content. In the code example you posted it seems it is JSON content that URL is fetching.
Create your own implementation of readFromStream() and you would be good to go.